# Need Calendar Icon next to textBox using Dojo

Tags: dojo, calendar

I need a Dojo code for DateText box and a Calendar Icon next to that and when i click in that Icon i should get Calendar and I should be able to select the date from the calendar . I have tried with dijit.form.DateTextBox , but it is not giving calendar Icon . Can you please help me .

Thank you,
Amarnath.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `dijit.form.DateTextBox` with the following css.

```
.dijitDateTextBox .dijitArrowButtonInner {
  background: transparent url(PATH_TO_IMAGE) center center no-repeat;
  width: 16px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

There are icons on the internet that you can use.  Make sure the license is appropriate for the application you are working on.

I have used these in the past:

http://www.freeiconsweb.com/Free-Downloads.asp?id=66

Comment: Thanks Craig.its working , I am able to display Calendar Icon  .